# Appcelerator android application crash always after permission change in device setting

Tags: android, permissions, titanium, appcelerator, setting

Appcelerator android application crashing  after changing the camera or location permission from device setting or changing the language in device setting. I am getting the error message when taping the application icon like'org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!'.

This the log i am getting

```
02-17 14:31:55.499: E/InputDispatcher(778): channel '6959912 com.my.myapp/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
02-17 14:35:02.079: A/libc(18349): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 18371 (KrollRuntimeThr)
02-17 14:35:02.180: A/DEBUG(196): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-17 14:35:02.180: A/DEBUG(196): Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:6.0.1/M4B30X/3237893:user/release-keys'
02-17 14:35:02.180: A/DEBUG(196): Revision: '11'
02-17 14:35:02.180: A/DEBUG(196): ABI: 'arm'
02-17 14:35:02.180: A/DEBUG(196): pid: 18349, tid: 18371, name: KrollRuntimeThr  >>> com.my.myapp <<<
02-17 14:35:02.180: A/DEBUG(196): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
02-17 14:35:02.197: A/DEBUG(196):     r0 00000000  r1 aeea9000  r2 75646f4d  r3 0000656c
02-17 14:35:02.197: A/DEBUG(196):     r4 00000000  r5 9ba20dc8  r6 ab418020  r7 00000000
02-17 14:35:02.197: A/DEBUG(196):     r8 00000000  r9 9ba1cd78  sl a09534e4  fp b6cc0ec0
02-17 14:35:02.197: A/DEBUG(196):     ip a0f815d0  sp a0953430  lr 9b1fcfa3  pc 9b2db0d0  cpsr a0070010
02-17 14:35:02.199: A/DEBUG(196): backtrace:
02-17 14:35:02.199: A/DEBUG(196):     #00 pc 003a70d0  /data/app/com.my.myapp-2/lib/arm/libkroll-v8.so (_ZN2v86Object3GetENS_5LocalINS_5ValueEEE+8)
02-17 14:35:02.200: A/DEBUG(196):     #01 pc 002c8f9f  /data/app/com.my.myapp-2/lib/arm/libkroll-v8.so (Java_org_appcelerator_kroll_runtime_v8_V8Runtime_nativeRunModule+106)
02-17 14:35:02.200: A/DEBUG(196):     #02 pc 0100c61d  /data/app/com.my.myapp-2/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0xb32000)
02-17 14:35:02.603: A/DEBUG(196): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_03
02-17 14:35:02.603: E/DEBUG(196): AM write failed: Broken pipe
02-17 14:35:02.650: E/lowmemorykiller(190): Error opening /proc/18349/oom_score_adj; errno=2
```

Comment: add your code and error log!

Comment: must be related to your code, don't have any of the issues

Comment: Are you using liveview?